# Splitting Columns that contain decimal point values in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I facing difficulties splitting columns in R. For instance

```
        Col1.Col2.Col3 
        12.3,10,11
        11.3,11,50
        85,89.3,90
        and over 100x records
```

I did

```
       tidyr::separate(df, Col1.Col2.Col3, 
                c("Col1", "Col2", "Col3" ))
```

And i get

```
        Col1 Col2 Col3 
        12   3    10
        11   3    11
        85   89   3
        and over 100x records
```

I realised that the decimal value is moved to the next column and the values of Col3 were left out. How can i fix this or is there a better way of splitting the columns?

Comment: How are you reading the data source?

Comment: separate function has sep argument, `sep = ","`

Comment: I did df <- read.csv('df.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ';')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyr::separate` has a `sep` argument that controls where the splits occur.  Use `sep = ","`.